# How to divide one column by another where one dataframe's column value corresponds to another dataframe's column's value in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Consider the following data frames in Python Pandas:

#### DataframeA

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | 439 |
| 1 | cat | 932 |
| 1 | frog | 932 |
| 2 | dog | 2122 |
| 2 | cat | 454 |
| 2 | frog | 773 |
| 3 | dog | 9223 |
| 3 | cat | 3012 |
| 3 | frog | 898 |

#### DataframeB

| ColD | ColE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 314 |
| 3 | 124 |

To note, ColB just repeats it's string values as ColA iterates upwards. ColC and ColE are random. ColA and ColD correspond. ColD values will never have repeats (like a map).

**I want to divide ColC by ColE wherever ColA == ColD** and ideally put the resulting value in a new column in DataframeA (or just have it overwrite ColC). The resulting value should be able to have decimals.

How can I do this in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `.map`

if you have multiple keys to join on then `merge` would be more useful as demonstrated by @anky

```
df1['ColF'] = df1['ColC'] / df1['ColA'].map(df2.set_index(['ColD'])['ColE'])

ColA   ColB  ColC       ColF
0     1   dog    439   4.346535
1     1   cat    932   9.227723
2     1  frog    932   9.227723
3     2   dog   2122   6.757962
4     2   cat    454   1.445860
5     2  frog    773   2.461783
6     3   dog   9223  74.379032
7     3   cat   3012  24.290323
8     3  frog    898   7.241935
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you can merge and then divide , just for a new df use below else use @Manakin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65872525/9840637).

```
out = (df_a.merge(df_b,left_on='ColA',right_on='ColD',how='left')
.assign(new=lambda x:x['ColC'].div(x['ColE'])).reindex(columns=[*df_a.columns]+['new']))
```

---

```
print(out)

   ColA  ColB  ColC        new
0     1   dog   439   4.346535
1     1   cat   932   9.227723
2     1  frog   932   9.227723
3     2   dog  2122   6.757962
4     2   cat   454   1.445860
5     2  frog   773   2.461783
6     3   dog  9223  74.379032
7     3   cat  3012  24.290323
8     3  frog   898   7.241935
```

Comment: good solution if there are more keys to join on other than `ColA` feels a little complex tho  ?

Comment: @Manakin sorry didnt get you , `left_on` and `right_on` supports list of column names. or if there are matching column names then one can use the suffixes arg: `(df_a.merge(df_b,left_on='ColA',right_on='ColD',how='left',suffixes=('','_y'))
 .assign(new=lambda x:x['ColC'].div(x['ColE'])).reindex(columns=[*df_a.columns]+['new']))` that way it  retains the original names and reindex works

Comment: ah sorry i meant that the `keys` as in more than one column to join on, the assign and div/reindex felt a little complex.

Comment: @Manakin right then you may have to break it dow to multiple lines.